# Можно ли перемещать блоки интерфейса в фреймворке Flet, просто указав их значение?

Tags: python, flet

В общем, есть такой фреймворк для python называется Flet: [https://flet.dev/docs/controls/column#horizontal_alignment]. Используется он для создания интерфейсов и т.д. Я накидал себе макет меню, но хотел бы перемещать элементы блоками, как в CSS (во Flet только несколько состояний), но перемещение работает для всех блоков, указать по отдельности не получается. (Есть Row - горизонталь, Comumn - вертикаль).

В коде на 46 строке, я бы хотел поместить `horizontal_alignment = ft.CrossAxisAlignment.END`, но работает только если написать `page.horizontal_alignment = ft.CrossAxisAlignment.END` и то уже после `ft.Column(...)` на 48 строке (когда так пишу, состояние начинает работать для всех блоков Column)

Код ниже:

```
import flet as ft

def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.title = "Anime Payment System"
    # page.window_full_screen = True
    
    # page.vertical_alignment = ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER
    # page.horizontal_alignment = ft.CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER

    profile = ft.Container(
        content=ft.Text("Profile", size=20),
        alignment=ft.alignment.center,
        width=250,
        height=50,
        border_radius=10,
        ink=True,
        on_click=lambda e: print("Profile"))
    
    settings = ft.Container(
        content=ft.Text("Settings", size=20),
        alignment=ft.alignment.center,
        width=250,
        height=50,
        border_radius=10,
        ink=True,
        on_click=lambda e: print("Settings"))
    
    support = ft.Container(content=ft.Text("Support", size=20),
        alignment=ft.alignment.center,
        width=250,
        height=50,
        border_radius=10,
        ink=True,
        on_click=lambda e: print("Support"))
    
    faq = ft.Container(
        content=ft.Text("FAQ", size=20),
        alignment=ft.alignment.center,
        width=250,
        height=50,
        border_radius=10,
        ink=True,
        on_click=lambda e: print("FAQ"))

    #!
    profile_column = ft.Column(controls=[profile, settings, support, faq])

    page.horizontal_alignment = ft.CrossAxisAlignment.END
    page.add(profile_column)

ft.app(target=main)
```